# Update Database by republishing

Tags: database, umbraco, web-deployment

this is my problem:

When working in webmatrix, if I have a published Umbraco site and I need to re-publish it to update the live version to my local version and I need to update the database too, I can't.

Webmatrix will say that the database file is in use. Of course it's in use, 'cause IIS is running on the server, and the site is live, so it's using its database, and it can't be overwritten.

What bugs me the most is that I haven't found any way to overcome this problem, if not by stopping my website's application pool on my server, or restarting the IIS service, but that's too much fuss!

There's got to be a simple way to update the database from Webmatrix.

I usually use a SQL CE database for my Umbraco websites but I can switch if SQL Server is needed.

Please, this is driving me nuts, I hope it's possible and someone will show me the way!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the app_offline.htm [method outlined here](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/using-umbraco-with-an-embedded-sql-server-database-%28sql-server-express-user-instance%29). Basically you can add a file to the root of the website called app_offline.htm and this will allow you to update the database. Obviously, you can format the app_offline.htm page to look like your site and have a some copy stating the site will be back up in a few minutes etc.

On a different note, moving the database to SQL Server causes a similar issue in that, although you can update the db without having to detach it, you still have to prevent people from accessing the site whilst the update is occurring.

Comment: It worked! It's still far from an automatic kind of update, but it's better : D Thank you!